# How are Clow Reed and Fei Wong Reed related in Tsubasa Reservoir Chronicle?

Tags: tsubasa-chronicle

Considering that Clow Reed and Fei Wong Reed have the same surnames and that they both have magical powers, how are they related? It was not clearly stated on the anime series or manga how they are related (unless I overlooked it). Are they brothers or relatives? Or do they just coincidentally have the same surnames? (Though Yuko said there is no such thing as coincidence, there is only inevitability.)

I'll appreciate any details. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Tsubasa Wikia](http://tsubasa.wikia.com/):

> Fei Wong Reed also mentions Clow quite frequently, and he's also a descendant of Clow.

This is shown in chapter 64, which appears in Volume 9 of the manga. He is described as somewhat of a distant relative of Clow Reed.

Information for this can be found on: [Fei Wang Reed's Wikia page](http://tsubasa.wikia.com/wiki/Fei_Wang_Reed) and Fei Wang Reed's section on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tsubasa:_Reservoir_Chronicle_characters#Fei-Wang_Reed). The citing is provided on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: So they are just relatives. I see. Thanks for the info.

Comment: In [Chapter 233, page 20](http://i.imgur.com/eYzUH.jpg), of the Tsubasa Chronicles manga, Kurogane has a conversation with Fai and Fai mentions that Fei Wang could have been the afterimage of a wish made by someone with a great magical power. So instead of a relative, this might mean that it might be an unintentional (side) effect of a wish made by Clow.

Answer (score 0):

Fei-Wang Reed was born from the wish Clow Reed made to revive Yuko. I think this goes far beyond being heavily implied, as it is pretty much confirmed by his actions, his motivations, and his dialogue. For instance, when he dies in chapter 231, he says,

> The witch must be revived... That's the whole reason for my existence... And the message I must deliver to her... That is my reason... I am to...

Additionally, he shatters to pieces, his body falling apart after death as with all the clones in the series who died. I believe he is a clone of Clow Reed, in the same way Watanuki is a clone of Syaoran. Since Clow Reed was unable to revive Yuko, part of Fei-Wang Reed's motivations is to prove he is superior to Clow, by accomplishing what Clow could not do. It's possible that Fei-Wang was born from Clow Reed's regrets at having had to give up, and thus why he is so determined to carry out the wish.

But regardless of my little speculation spree, considering Watanuki was born from stopping Sakura's time, it isn't so far-fetched to think Fei-Wang was born from stopping Yuko's.

Here's what Fai has to say when Kurogane asks why Fei-Wang broke into pieces:

> I don't know. But it may be that Fei-Wang... he himself was an image of somebody else. Or perhaps less a person... and more a very strong will. It could be the personification of a wish left behind by someone with enormous magical power.

As far as the story goes, the only known characters who fit the bill of having such powerful magical power are Clow Reed and Sakura. We also happen to know Clow Reed made a wish to save Yuko, so it seems like it's a mystery solved.

We could get into speculation and say there's simply some unknown character. There is simply no information to support such a theory, however, and I believe if that was the conclusion the authors wanted us to reach, they would have laid the groundwork.